# Reduce spacing between Bootstrap row-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How should I remove spacing between multiple `row-fluid` elements using Bootstrap?

I tried creating another class called `.top-buffer` and `.bottom-buffer` like this:

```
.top-buffer { margin-top:-5px; }
.bottom-buffer { bottom:-5px; }
```

And then I applied those like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid top-buffer">
  <div class="span4">

  </div>
</div>
```

Positive numbers do indeed increase the buffer, but the negative numbers seem to have no effect.

Comment: You can override the `.row-fluid` margins `.row-fluid{margin:0;}` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/YPA8Q/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that what I really wanted to do was reduce the space inside of a span rather than a row.  And adding the top-buffer class to the span works!